# ZendX DatePicker issue under Ajax request

Tags: jquery-ui, zendx

I am facing issue while i load a form on ajax request. i followed the steps :

1. Enable jqueryUi in layout.
2. creates a form element like :

   ```
   $dob = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker('patient_dob');
   $dob->setLabel('')
          ->addFilter('StripTags')
          ->addFilter('StringTrim')
          //->addValidator('Date')
          ->setAttrib('readonly', 'true')
          ->setJQueryParam('dateFormat', 'yy-mm-d')
          ->setDecorators(array(
   'Description', 'Errors', 'UiWidgetElement',
   array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'Div', 'class'=>'calender_input'))
                ));
   ```

   and just called the element into form. It is working when page load normally but not with ajax request. What is the reason? any suggestions? i googled a lot about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the javascript code that activates the date picker is rendered by the ZendX_Jquery extension to happen when the document is ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<!--
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#patient_dob").datepicker({});
});
//-->

</script>
```

which makes sense with non-ajax requests, but never is executed in an ajax request because the document.ready has already happened in the parent's page.  You can add your own in your view directly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#patient_dob").datepicker({});
</script>
```

I haven't yet found a solution for this from the Zend Jquery extension, but if you do please let me know!

Comment: It working for me if i add script like you show, But actually if we want to add this script in zend manner, then how it could be possible? still searching for the same.